# Unable to cancel the notification from the notification tray when different layouts used for expand/collapse

Tags: android, notifications, android-remoteview

I have a share option in the notification tray. So, I have used 2 custom views in my code.

```
1. Expandable Notification Layout
2. Normal Notification Layout
```

The UI is working fine. But, notifications are misbehaving. If I click the `first notification or share first item` in the notification, it works perfectly. But, If I click the `last notification`, then it opens the app but notification is not cleared from the notification tray. Also, the strange thing is, after clicking the notification,`small icon` which comes in the status bar disappears and now if i click the notification, it doesn't respond. I'm cancelling the notification. That's why second time, when i click it doesn't work. This was not happening when I used default builder layout for normal view. 
Here is my code:

//setup a expanded notification layout

```
 RemoteViews expandedView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification); 
  expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image_logo, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        String time = dateFormat.format(new Date(when));
            expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.current_time, time);
            expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));


            expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
expandedView.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(R.id.share, R.drawable.gcm_share, 0, 0, 0);
```

//set a normal notification layout

```
    RemoteViews collapsedView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_normal_layout);
    collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
            notificationId = ((int) System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000000);
```

//register listenr for Share Icon

```
setBtnListeners(expandedView, requestID, message, context, notificationId);


            `Bitmap largeIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).getBitmap()`;
```

//Construct notification Builder

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
         mNotifyBuilder
                            .setWhen(when)
                            .setSmallIcon(icon)
                            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                            .setContentTitle(message)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
            notification = mNotifyBuilder.build();
```

//assign the vies to the notification builder

```
 notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
            notification.contentView = collapsedView;
```

//create pending Intent

```
Intent notificationIntent;

        //notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Launcher.class);
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);//Sritapana189
        notificationIntent.putExtra(BundleKeys.NORMAL_PUSH, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(BundleKeys.DEFAULT_NOTI_NAV, nav);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(BundleKeys.FROM_GCM, true);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.GCMKeys.GCM_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, 0); //Modified
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

//Registering the share icon of notification tray

```
   private static void setBtnListeners(RemoteViews notificationView, int requestId, String message, Context context, int notificationId) {
        Intent shareBtnIntent = new Intent(context, GcmTransparentActivity.class);
        shareBtnIntent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.GCMKeys.BREAKING_NEWS, message);
        shareBtnIntent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.GCMKeys.GCM_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestId, shareBtnIntent, 0);
        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.share, pendingIntent);
    }
```

//SplashActivity recieving Pending Inent

//here I'm retrieving the payload data and saving it and then cancelling the notification

```
Utility.cancelNotification(gcmNotificationId, getApplicationContext());


public static void cancelNotification(int id, Context ctx) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(id);
    }
```

The only change i did in my code is I added custom layout for the normal view.After this change, it's misbehaving when last notification item is clicked. Is there anything I'm missing. please help me to sort out this strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

problem may be because you are not getting the notification id properly
quick fix can be,

`Notification nNotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancel(id);`

replace this with ,

```
Notification nNotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

Comment: According to my requirement only the clicked item must be cancelled. So, I cannot use cancelAll() method

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. The problem was with the `RemoteViews`. I had made them local and making them final solved my issue

```
 final RemoteViews expandedView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification); 
final RemoteViews collapsedView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_normal_layout)
```